# Trouble in exam earlier today - ArrayList methods

Tags: java, android, list, collections, arraylist

I had a exam for a course named "Java for Android I" earlier today and found this question that I just don't get. Maybe some of you could explain it for me.

Question:

> View this collection *ArrayList  p*. A class Person is a
>   superclass to Student. ArrayList implements the List-interface
>   (according to the Java-API).
>
> The compiler wont allow some of the situations noted in the code. Why?
>   Describe how they may entail that *p* wont contain instances of Person
>   or why *p* is not a *ArrayList* . E.g. *p.add("Hello");* now
>   contains a String instance.

Code:

```
p = new ArrayList<Object>();

void method ( ArrayList<Student> als) { ... }

void method ( List<Person> lp ) { ... }

void method ( ArrayList<Object> alo) { ... }
```

How would you describe this question? I just don't get what my professor want's me to answer.

Sorry if the quote has messed up grammar. I've been translating it from swedish.

Comment: Is that the complete code of the question??

Comment: What does `p` have to do with the method declarations?

Comment: i'm guessing there are some things lost in translation...

Comment: I agree, this sounds very confusing.

Comment: it makes sense if he's wanting to know why you can/can't pass the variable p to the methods shown.  That's what @YuRDeD is getting at in his answer

Comment: I'm afraid theres nothing lost in the translation. That is what the question said and thats why me and my classmates are pretty confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your professor's question is about the basics of type checking in Java generics. Assuming:

```
class Person {
}

class Student extends Person {
}
```

This is a valid snippet:

```
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

as is this:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

This is obviously not valid, because an object can be a `Person` instance without being a `Student` instance:

```
List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

But *this* is my favorite - it always trips people up:

```
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

This is an invalid snippet. "What? Why!" I hear you ask. Well, it's true that all `Student` objects are also instances of `Person`, so that assignments like this work:

```
Person person = new Student();
```

When it comes to parametric types, though, the Java compiler does its best to protect you. Imagine this piece of code:

```
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Student>();

list.add(new Person());
```

If the compiler did not object to the assignment, it would be now possible to enter `Person` objects to an `ArrayList` that only hosts `Student` objects...

Method calls work in exactly the same way. Just strip the type of the argument from the method signature and try to imagine an assignment to that type...

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to tell for sure from what you've provided, but it seems that the professor is likely trying to test your understanding of some subtleties with generics.

The fact that he doesn't show the declaration of the reference p is a clue.

This is legal if passed the reference p:

> method(ArrayList<\Object> alo)  //because the type and parameter
>   matches exactly

These are illegal:

```
method(ArrayList<Student> als) //because the method will expect Student and will get Object
method(List<Person>) //same reason.. expects list of Person, and will get Objects
```

Comment: Your probably right, I think I get the question now. Still think the question was written really bad. Thank's for the help bro! :)

Answer (score 0):

Didn't completely understand your question, though

The first method and third methods are duplicate methods as per the Java overLoading rule. Compiler will say they are duplicate methods.

Answer (score 0):

Or it might be about the following - I don't know for sure :)

```
// take some method
void method ( ArrayList<Object> ) { /* ... */ }

// and an Object
ArrayList<Object> p = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Now you can say `method(p)` and it will work because method expects an `ArrayList<Object>`. But

```
ArrayList<Student> q = new ArrayList<Student>();
method ( q );
```

will not work. Because `ArrayList<Student>` is not an `ArrayList<Object>` although `Studend extends Object`. To allow that you have to define the method:

```
void method ( ArrayList<? extends Object> ) { /* ... */ }
// or shorter but the same
void method ( ArrayList<?> ) { /* ... */ }
```

If you want a method that can take both `ArrayList<Person>` and `ArrayList<Student>` (and all other subclasses of Person) you have to declare it

```
void method ( ArrayList<? extends Person>) { /* ... */ }
```